# What's the most effective way to create a curved rectangle in inkscape

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve

[image]

[image]

Hi, I'm trying to create that figure in a fast and symmetrical way, I've tried several methods but all of them are either too complicated or not symmetrical. I know there should be a way to make that curve symmetrical and the rectangle of certain width. I'd appreciate your help

Comment: turn gridsnap on, draw two concentric circles and a square then use booleans to build your c.

Comment: Stroke on circle path. Set stroke weight to desired shape width. Cut path.. expand to shape... at least in Illustrator.. no clue in Inkscape but I imagine something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one method

1. Draw a rectangle with a thick stroke and no fill, click and drag the radius control to round the ends to a semi-circle
2. Do *Path > Object to path*, to convert the rectangle to a normal path object
3. Select the two segments on the left and delete them using the Delete Segments button
4. Nudge the selected nodes closer to the other nodes by using the arrow key on your keyboard
5. You can do *Path > Stroke to Path* to convert the stroke to a path if you want. However, be careful here as Stroke to Path is destructive, and can't be turned back into a stroke if you want to re-edit it later. Skip this step and leave it as a stroke if you want to be able to edit it as a stroke.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this works better for me. I tried using a two circles and a rectangle to get the division of the shapes. but the final result was difficult to manipulate. I like this method. Thanks!