# Inkscape : simultaneously adjust multiple Bezier handles on rectangles?

Tags: inkscape, bezier-curve

I need to create an C-shaped outline. Essentially, I hope that more than one Bezier handle can move simultaneously. I do not mean the two handles associated with one node, but the Bezier handles from many different nodes.

My first approach is using Inkscape to :

1. create a rectangle [left row icon]
2. Path->Object-to-Path [top row menu]
3. edit nodes [left column icon between pointer and rectangle]
4. show Bezier handles of selected nodes [top row, right side icon]

I can shift-click any nodes to form a group. There are six nodes, but I'll leave that for now. The group of nodes can move around as expected, e.g. one side of the rectangle while others are fixed. I can click the nodes to get different Bezier handles. At this point, I would like to change the rectangle as if bending it into a C-shape with my hands, so that all the dimensions change simultaneously. It seems possible if the Bezier handles of four nodes could be adjusted so the lines between the selected nodes all moved in concert. I am reading the dialogue on the bottom row for ideas, the closest being Shift-Y to keep symmetric - but that only works for one node.

Perhaps a C-shape formed from a rectangle, or Inkscape, is not the approach, or the Bezier handle idea is wrong.

programs:

Inkscape 1.1.2

Ubuntu 22.04.1

Comment: seems to me that this is essentially a duplicate of https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/160136/whats-the-most-effective-way-to-create-a-curved-rectangle-in-inkscape Also have you considered gridsnapping?

Comment: Im not sure, because this one exemplifies whats wrong with the answer to the other question. It happens to work, in this case and it probably how i would do it. but it does not fundamentally adress the conceotual problem your against.

Comment: [ deleted prev. comment ]  ... yes, that helps immensely. The linked answer appears to solve it for a filled C shape - in contrast, I need an outline of the C. I am trying to do this now - seems so close.

Comment: OK - The question about the Bezier handles is not answered. But in the meantime, I used the above info to [1] produce an outline of a C from a circle which forms open ends - draw two lines to close those ends [Bezier curve /line icon]... also can draw a half-circle.. and also [2]. I made an outline of a, say, rectangular staple shape, starting from the rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simultaneously adjust multiple Bézier handles in Inkscape. It's just not possible. I mean you could do it using guides/a grid/snapping etc, but that's not simultaneous or automatic.

However you could perhaps use a Mirror Symmetry Live Path Effect in Inkscape under some circumstances.

Here's an example

[image]

If you need to, you can bake in Path Effects using *Path > Obeject to Path*, this will give you two shapes, which you can unite using a Boolean Union operation.

Here's where the Shape Builder tool is located. To use it select a bunch of shapes, and hit the tool. Click and drag across shapes you want to unite, and Shift+Click to remove pieces.

[image]

Here's a quick example, using your C shape example from your other question with this new New Shape builder tool in Inkscape 1.3. It's a little buggy still, but it works. You could of course do this with boolean operations in Inkscape 1.2, but it's not as much fun.

[image]

Comment: Slould we merge the questions? +1

Comment: @joojaa - Maybe, I have no objection if the mods want to do so.

Comment: amazing answer - wow - I'll be trying these ideas later - thank you!